# R exclude if any column contains -1

Tags: r, subset

I have to exclude data if any one of around 80 columns from my dataset has the value -1. The total number of columns is 100 and the other 20 columns are allowed to have -1 values.
I know this can be done by using subset, something like:

```
keep_data <- subset(foo, Var1 != -1 | Var2 != -1 | Var3 != -1 ....... upto Var80)
```

Can this be done in any other way where I do not need to pass all 80 variables in subset, instead can I pass a list or some other method?

Comment: How about something like `keep_data[apply(keep_data, 1, function(x) !any(x==-1)),]`?

Comment: @AndrewGustar The problem with using any is that there are around 100 columns in my data, and some others (other than these 80) are allowed to have -1 values.

Comment: @Ryan Can you please explain how your code works?

Comment: @VisheshShrivastav Ignore that comment, I misunderstood the question. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `cols` as a character vector instead of numeric if you want

```
cols <- 2:4 #Columns which we'll check for -1

# Remove rows for which any of cols (defined above) are -1
subset(df, !rowSums(df[cols] == -1))

#You can also use brackets instead of subset
df[!rowSums(df[cols] == -1),]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the explanation!